# Can I/How to... call a protected function outside of a class in PHP

Tags: php, function, call, protected

I have a protected function that is defined within a certain class. I want to be able to call this protected function outside of the class within another function. Is this possible and if so how may I achieve it

```
class cExample{

   protected function funExample(){
   //functional code goes here

   return $someVar
   }//end of function

}//end of class


function outsideFunction(){

//Calls funExample();

}
```

Comment: You can't. That'd defeat the purpose of having a protected function in the first place. You could have a public method which invokes the protected method on your behalf, but then why have a protected method to begin with?

Comment: A duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/12255740/2088851

Answer (score 22, accepted):

That's the point of OOP - encapsulation:

**Private**

```
Only can be used inside the class. Not inherited by child classes.
```

**Protected**

```
Only can be used inside the class and child classes. Inherited by child classes.
```

**Public**

```
Can be used anywhere. Inherited by child classes.
```

If you still want to trigger that function outside, you can declare a public method that triggers your protected method:

```
protected function b(){

}

public function a(){
  $this->b() ;
  //etc
}
```

Comment: You can access another instance' protected member if they both extend the same abstract class. [I didn't believe it until I saw it.](https://gist.github.com/flowl/774c6e6335b6cb205c352ad67af2799c)

Answer (score 71):

Technically, it is possible to invoke private and protected methods using the reflection API.  However, 99% of the time doing so is a really bad idea.  If you can modify the class, then the correct solution is probably to just make the method public.  After all, if you need to access it outside the class, that defeats the point of marking it protected.

Here's a quick reflection example, in case this is one of the very few situations where it's really necessary:

```
<?php
class foo { 
    protected function bar($param){
        echo $param;
    }
}

$r = new ReflectionMethod('foo', 'bar');
$r->setAccessible(true);
$r->invoke(new foo(), "Hello World");
```

Comment: This is the correct answer for people who know what they are doing.

Comment: Sidenote: This is available in PHP 5.4+ (Yeah!)

Comment: Any changes/new possibilities in 2018 ?

Comment: This is pure gold (And the actual answer to the question)

Comment: This could be useful for test, besides that purrr evil

Answer (score 9):

If the parent's method is protected, you can use an anonymous class:

```
class Foo {
    protected function do_foo() {
        return 'Foo!';
    }
}

$bar = new class extends Foo {
    public function do_foo() {
      return parent::do_foo();
    }
}

$bar->do_foo(); // "Foo!"
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.anonymous.php

Comment: I like this approach as it maintains the semantics of OOP

Answer (score 6):

Another option (PHP 7.4)

```
<?php
class cExample {
   protected function funExample(){
       return 'it works!';
   }
}

$example = new cExample();

$result = Closure::bind(
    fn ($class) => $class->funExample(), null, get_class($example)
)($example);

echo $result; // it works!
```

Comment: On PHP 7.3, I got the following error: `syntax error, unexpected '=>' (T_DOUBLE_ARROW), expecting ')'`

I had to use this syntax instead: `$result = Closure::bind(function ($class) { return $class->funExample(); }, null, get_class($example))($example);`

Answer (score 4):

You can override this class with another where you make this public.

```
class cExample2 extends cExample {
  public function funExample(){
    return parent::funExample()
  }
}
```

(note this won't work with private members)

But the idea of private and protected members is to NOT BE called from outside.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to share code between your classes you can use traits, but it depends how you want use your function/method.

Anyway

```
trait cTrait{
   public function myFunction() {
      $this->funExample();
   }
}

class cExample{
   use cTrait;

   protected function funExample() {
   //functional code goes here

   return $someVar
   }//end of function

}//end of class

$object = new cExample();
$object->myFunction();
```

This will work, but keep in mind that you don't know what your class is made of this way. If you change the trait then all of your classes which use it will be altered as well. It's also good practice to write an interface for every trait you use.

Answer (score 2):

here i can give you one example like below

```
<?php
    class dog {
        public $Name;
        private function getName() {
            return $this->Name;
        }
    }

    class poodle extends dog {
        public function bark() {
            print "'Woof', says " . $this->getName();
        }
    }

    $poppy = new poodle;
    $poppy->Name = "Poppy";
    $poppy->bark();
?>
```

or one another way to use with latest php

In PHP you can do this using Reflections. To invoke protected or private methods use the setAccessible() method http://php.net/reflectionmethod.setaccessible  (just set it to TRUE)

Answer (score 0):

I am using Laravel. i was facing issue while access **protected** method outside of **class**.

```
   $bookingPriceDetails = new class extends BookingController {
        public function quotesPrice( $req , $selectedFranchise) {
           return parent::quotesPrice($req , $selectedFranchise);
        }
    };

     return $bookingPriceDetails->quotesPrice($request , selectedFranchisees());
```

here `BookingController` is **Class** name from which i want to get `protected` method. `quotesPrice( $req , $selectedFranchise)` is method that i want to access in different Class.